# What is the purpose of withDefaults() is Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

As per `Spring Security` at [Customizer's withDefaults()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/Customizer.html#withDefaults()) indicates:

> Returns a `Customizer` that does not alter the input argument.

But what does this exactly mean?

For e.g. what is the result if I use it like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable()
         .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
         .httpBasic(withDefaults());
     return http.build();
   }

}
```

Comment: It means if you use the `Customizer` returned by `withDefaults()` then that customizer will not customize anything (i.e. using it will mean the default settings will be applied).

Answer (score 10):

According to [java doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#httpBasic(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)), we have

```
 public HttpSecurity httpBasic(Customizer<HttpBasicConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> httpBasicCustomizer) throws Exception {
            httpBasicCustomizer.customize((HttpBasicConfigurer)this.getOrApply(new HttpBasicConfigurer()));
            return this;
        }
```

The parameter is of type `Customizer<HttpBasicConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>` which can be used as a lambda function to pass the changes that you want to be applied in the configurer that you provide to the `httpBasic` method. This method also returns the built `HttpSecurity` so the configurer is already applied, when the `httpBasic(....)` method ends.

A relative to your example let's name it **Example 1**

```
httpSecurity.httpBasic(httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> {
                          httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer.realmName("My Realm");
                          httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new YourAuthEntryClass());
                          })
    .authorizeRequests().and().csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated());
```

So the configurer is going to apply the `realmName` and `authenticationEntryPoint` to the `httpSecurity` via the lambda function which you  have provided.

In case you didn't want to make any modifications to the `httpSecurity` inside the `httpBasic` method you could as well have done the

```
httpSecurity.httpBasic(httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> {} )
       .authorizeRequests().and().csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated());
```

And Spring just to avoid writting this nonsese `httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> {}` as parameter has also gave you this with static `withDefaults` method in the functional interface `Customizer`. Keep in mind that this `Customizer` is just a generic Interface and will be used in other places as well not just here.

> ```
> @FunctionalInterface
> public interface Customizer<T> {
>     void customize(T t);
>
>     static <T> Customizer<T> withDefaults() {
>         return (t) -> {
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```

So to avoid the

```
  httpSecurity.httpBasic(httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> {} )....
```

you can as well write

```
 httpSecurity.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())....
```

meaning no configuration will be applied inside the `httpBasic` method in the `httpSecurity` object.

**Keep in mind however**,
that you also have available another method from [Java Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#httpBasic())

> ```
>    public HttpBasicConfigurer<HttpSecurity> httpBasic() throws Exception {
>                 return (HttpBasicConfigurer)this.getOrApply(new HttpBasicConfigurer());
>             }
> ```

which could be used as well and this doesn't return the modified `httpSecurity` object but an `HttpBasicConfigurer` instead which could be written as to modify the `httpSecurity` using the builder pattern.

So the **Example 1** could now be written as

```
httpSecurity.httpBasic()
            .realmName("My Realm")
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new YourAuthEntryClass())
            .and().authorizeRequests().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated());
```

And in case you didn't want to apply any basic http configuration changes to the `httpSecurity` you could just skip the methods `realmName` and `authenticationEntryPoint` from the builder pattern, and it would have provide you again with the default basic configurations for `httpSecurity`

```
httpSecurity.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated());
```

which would be exactly the same with the version of

```
httpSecurity.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated());
```

Answer (score 0):

use default setting.

for ex,

1. whom to authorize
2. how to authorize