# Spring Security in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently in the process of migrating our REST application from Spring Boot 2.7.5 to 3.0.0-RC2. I want everything to be secure apart from the Open API URL. In Spring Boot 2.7.5, we used to do this:

```java
@Named
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/openapi/openapi.yml").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
  }
}
```

and it worked fine. In Spring Boot 3, I had to change it to

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/openapi/openapi.yml").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated())
        .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

since WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has been removed. It's not working though. The Open API URL is also secured via basic authentication. Have I made a mistake when upgrading the code or is that possibly an issue in Spring Boot 3 RC 2?

**Update**
Since most of the new API was already available in 2.7.5, I've updated our code in our 2.7.5 code base to the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .antMatchers(OPTIONS).permitAll() // allow CORS option calls for Swagger UI
            .antMatchers("/openapi/openapi.yml").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

In our branch for 3.0.0-RC2, the code is now as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers(OPTIONS).permitAll() // allow CORS option calls for Swagger UI
            .requestMatchers("/openapi/openapi.yml").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

As you can see, the only difference is that I call requestMatchers instead of antMatchers. This method seems to have been renamed. The method antMatchers is no longer available. The end effect is still the same though. On our branch for 3.0.0-RC2, Spring Boot asks for basic authentication for the OpenAPI URL. Still works fine on 2.7.5.

Comment: I should probably mention that I'm using Jersey. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Do you actually have a handler(controller mapping)for `"/openapi/openapi.yml"`? If there is no handler, it is resolved to not `404 NOT_FOUND`. Which in turn redirects to `/error`.  Since `/error` is also secured it will ask you for login.

Comment: Yes, I do. Once I enter the credentials of basic authentication, the Open API is shown.

Comment: Update: You *must* use new version of Springdoc. https://springdoc.org/ . Focus at text *For spring-boot v3 support, make sure you use springdoc-openapi v2*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Author: https://github.com/wilkinsona

```java
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/openapi/openapi.yml")).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33357#issuecomment-1327301183

I recommend you use Spring Boot 3.0.0 (GA) right now, not RC version.

Answer (score 10):

Inside my WebSecurityConfig, I did this:

```java
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        // -- Swagger UI v2
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "swagger-resources/**",
        "/configuration/ui",
        "configuration/ui",
        "/configuration/security",
        "configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "swagger-ui.html",
        "webjars/**",
        // -- Swagger UI v3
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "swagger-ui/**",
        // CSA Controllers
        "/csa/api/token",
        // Actuators
        "/actuator/**",
        "/health/**"
};

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            //.addFilterAfter(authenticationJwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers( new AntPathRequestMatcher("swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers( new AntPathRequestMatcher("v3/api-docs/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**")).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic();
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

This and using Dockerfile (doing `mvn clean package` and running .jar from Docker) made me had no issues with authentication inside swagger ui.

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: What is the difference between the first and second method? They look the same, method and parameter names excluded. Could you not chain the instructions in the second bean into the first bean and delete the second bean altogether?

Comment: The second one use httpBasic() which is deprecated. The first one adds a Filter, that I use for Authentify requests and set httpBasics withDefaults() That add you the default behaviour, just like Panagiotis Bougioukos answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73529846/what-is-the-purpose-of-withdefaults-is-spring-security At the moment I wrote the answer, I tried a lot of different ways to make it work, and it wasn't successful. That configuration was the only one working in my case.

Answer (score 4):

My security cfg looks like:

Spring 3.0.0

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/static/**", "/index.html", "/api/users/me").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/login", "/api/users/{username}", "/api/users/logout", "/api/customers", "/api/storages").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/customers", "/api/storages").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/customers/{id}", "/api/storages/{id}").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/users/{id}", "/api/storages/{id}", "/api/customers/{id}").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().denyAll())
        .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
}
```

it works

Comment: @banan3'14 you edited what ? the space in a line - 1 tab ?

Comment: code indentation is now better and there's no word like *ot* – it instead. Even cosmetic changes are welcome on stackoverflow, as long as they improve the content – you can read more about that approach for example in this answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278091/7769052

Answer (score 4):

My security config looks like:

Spring 3.1.1

```
   http.csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.frameOptions(frameOptionsConfig -> frameOptionsConfig.disable())) //to make accessible h2 console, it works as frame
                .exceptionHandling(httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer -> httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

return http.build();
```

Comment: i used 3.1.1, i see a compile time error .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); as UsernamePasswordAuthentication still uses javax servlet, whereas OnceperRequestfilet is Jakarta

Comment: @Jayanth - It works for me: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Answer (score 2):

Use

```java
  http.securityMatcher("<patterns>")...
```

to specify authentication for endpoints.

```java
      authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("<pattern>")
```

only works for authorization, if you don't set `securityMatcher` , SecurityFilterChain by default  gets `any request` for authentication. And any request will be authenticated by an authentication provider.

In your case, you can define two security filter,  chains: one for public endpoitns, another for secured. And give them proper order:

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain configurePublicEndpoints(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher(OPTIONS,"/openapi/openapi.yml").csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .anyRequest().permitAll() // allow CORS option calls for Swagger UI
    );
        return http.build();
      }
    
    @Bean
    Order(2)
      public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher("/**")
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
      }
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex. I went with Andy Wilkinson's suggestion (see answer by James Grey)

Comment: This code also results in an error, as the same method name `configure` cannot be supplied twice.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation suggests an example which I have abridged here with your config:

```
http
  .authorizeExchange((exchanges) ->
    exchanges
      .pathMatchers("/openapi/openapi.yml").permitAll()
      .anyExchange().authenticated())
    .httpBasic();

return http.build();
```

You could try this, since it changes the "request" for the "exchange" wording, in line with the migration to declarative clients (@PostExchange vs. @PostMapping) I suppose. Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. HttpSecurity doesn't have a method authorizeExchange. Your example is for WebFlux which I'm not using:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.html

Answer (score -3):

This seems to be a bug in Spring Boot 3. I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33357).

Comment: I think it is not, please check securityMatcher() method for HttpSecurity