# Spring Security with multiple login pages using multiple filter chains only takes order 1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application where I have 2 login pages. I did the order annotation configuration however it only works as expected. So if I try to access any page with path (`/**`) it is permitted, any page with path (`/admin/**`) is redirected to admin login page but any page with path (`/user/**`) is not redirected to user login. How can I solve it?

```java
package com.business.config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import com.business.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailService;

  @Bean
  public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {

    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailService);

    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
        throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

@Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class AdminSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")).hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin-login")
                .permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class UserSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/**")).hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user-login")
                .permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Both filter chains are unrestricted, so the first filter chain is always applied.

Comment: @dur any suggestions on how I can improve it?

Comment: Did you read the last link, there is an example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74674241/5277820