# I can't configure Spring security in Spring 3.0, adding Keycloack to it, can anyone help me with a basic configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> @Slf4j

## WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecated and deleted in Spring boot 3.0

> public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

## configure chance HttpSecurity http with SecurityBuilder builder in spring 3.0

> @Override
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
> log.trace("configure(HttpSecurity http)");
> http.cors()
> .and()
> .csrf()
> .disable()
> .exceptionHandling()
> .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
> .and()
> .sessionManagement()
> .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
> .and()
> .authorizeRequests()
> .antMatchers("/**")
> .permitAll()
> .anyRequest()
> .authenticated();
> }

> }

Comment: You should refer to this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447778/spring-security-in-spring-boot-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3)