# 'csrf()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal

Tags: spring-boot

This is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/page/book","/page/food","/page/password");
```

but it says 'cors()' 'and()' 'csrf()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal

how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You resolve it by reading the [JavaDoc of `HttpSecurity#csrf`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#csrf()) and following the advice:

> **Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.**
> For removal in 7.0. Use `csrf(Customizer)` or `csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())` to stick with defaults. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html#_use_the_lambda_dsl) for more details.

So to use the same defaults as before, `csrf(Customizer.withDefault())` can be used, which is nothing more than [sugar for `csrf(() -> {})`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/Customizer.java#L39) (cf. [What is the purpose of withDefaults() is Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73529846/what-is-the-purpose-of-withdefaults-is-spring-security)).

The same applies when migrating the [`cors()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors()) configuration.